# What is the difference between permutation and randint in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

There is :

```
>>> np.random.permutation(5)
array([2, 0, 1, 4, 3])

>>> np.random.randint(0,5,5)
array([3, 4, 0, 2, 1])
```

Comment: it enables you to permute a pre-existing sequence which has a fixed content, for example np.random.permutation([5,5,5,1,1]) yields ... array([1, 5, 1, 5, 5])  with no other numbers other than the input values permuted

Comment: Also, `randint` draws "with replacement": some numbers can occur multiple times while others can be missing. It  doesn't happen in your example but that is mere coincidence.